# Constant Contact: Error message - Undefined offset: 1 in cc_class.php

Tags: php, constantcontact

I'm using PHP class from https://github.com/constantcontact/Constant-Contact-PHP-Sample-Contact-Forms to add new contacts to Constant Contact list, but recently I have got PHP error messages:

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Undefined offset: 1 
Filename: cc_class.php 
Line Number: 248

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 1
Filename: cc_class.php
Line Number: 252
```

where those lines look like:

(248)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($return);
```

(252)

```
}
```

and full related function to those two lines:

```
public  function subscriberExists($email = '') {
   $call = $this->apiPath.'/contacts?email='.$email;
   $return = $this->doServerCall($call);
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($return);
   $id = $xml->entry->id;
   if($id){ return $id; }
   else { return false; }
}
```

but it passes data to Constan Contact anyway.

Any clue what is going on there with those error messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the class [GitHub](https://github.com/constantcontact/Constant-Contact-PHP-Sample-Contact-Forms/issues/1#issuecomment-56695524)

> This is just a PHP notice, not a failure, when trying to access an
>   index of an array that hasn't been defined yet. The codebase in this
>   app is fairly old, and hasn't been brought up to date as PHP is
>   upgraded.
>
> We would recommend instead of using this repo, utilizing the newer PHP
>   SDK which is object-oriented, available via composer, and kept up to
>   date. You can definitely mute these notifications in your environment,
>   but this repo is deprecated, so this issue won't be addressed in the
>   project.